# Why does this CSS not take effect?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use a selector in my html，if I set the style in HTML, it looks normal.

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 0px">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="search" value="{{ search_word }}"  style="height: 30px "  onkeydown="entersearch()" placeholder="Enter to search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn" style="font-size: x-small">
            <!--<select id="idsel" class="form-control select-input" >-->
                <option value="campaignid">campaignid</option>
                <option value="vender" >vender</option>
                <option value="pkgname" >package</option>
           </select>
       </div>
 </div>
```

But when I changed it to set the style in CSS, it takes no effect...

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;margin-top: 0px">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="search" value="{{ search_word }}"  style="height: 30px "  onkeydown="entersearch()" placeholder="Enter to search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn" style="font-size: x-small">
             <select id="idsel" class="form-control select-input-gp" >
                <option value="campaignid">campaignid</option>
                <option value="vender" >vender</option>
                <option value="pkgname" >package</option>
             </select>
        </div>
```

```
<script type="text/css">
   .select-input-gp{
        height: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#337ab7;
        border-color:#2e6da4;
   }
</script>
```

It is strange. Can anyone give me a guide?

Comment: I have no idea what you're on about, but that is not a style - that's a script tag with a style-declaration. The correct tag to use is `<style type="text/css"></style>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<script type='text/css'>` use `<style type='text/css'>`

In your case, the whole style code would be this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .select-input-gp {
        height: 30px;
        width: 200px;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #337ab7;
        border-color: #2e6da4;
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `<script>` tag as you are not referencing a script; you are referencing a style so you need to replace it with a `<style>` tag.

The `<style>` tag should be declared in the `<head>` of your HTML, see [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningcss/a/aa021807.htm) for more.